# I so confused of this keyword in JS classes

Tags: javascript, this, arrow-functions, es6-class

[It may be difficult to read because I'm not a native English speaker.]

```js
class AnotherApp {
  constructor(arrowFunction, regularFunction) {
    this.arrowFunction = arrowFunction
    this.regularFunction = regularFunction
    this.foo()
  }
  foo() {
    this.arrowFunction()
    // this.regularFunction() // Error!!!
  }
}

class App {
  #apple = 'apple'
  constructor() {
    this.anotherApp = new AnotherApp(this.arrowFunction, this.regularFunction)
    this.arrowFunction()
    this.regularFunction()
  }
  arrowFunction = () => console.log(this.#apple)
  regularFunction(){
    console.log(this.#apple)
  }
}

const app = new App()
```

output:

```
apple
apple
apple
```

I learned that the `this` keyword when using arrow functions does not point to their own object, but points to the parent's execution context (EC).

[question 1.]

At the code above, when using classes, `this` of regular function and arrow function both point to the object in the same EC. Why is this happening?

[question 2.]

At the constructor of AnotherApp, arrowFunction gets assigned to this.arrowFunction

`this.arrowFunction = arrowFunction`

I expect `this` of this.arrowFuction to point to AnotherApp object, but it still points to the App object.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Read about this: https://javascript.info/object-methods
The exact answer should be: https://javascript.info/object-methods#arrow-functions-have-no-this

Answer (score 0):

1- to answer your first question, a better and simpler way to think about it is this:
`this` will always return the object that is executing the function, when using arrow functinos `this` would have the value of the object of where the arrow function is located lexically.

this is why you are getting an Error when calling this.regularFunction() because `this` would be the value of the object that is executing the current function which anotherApp, whilst it works in arrowFunction since this would always be App and only App object have access to that variable.

2- that is because accroding to the rule i gave you in 1, that arrow function is defined lexically within App and not AnotherApp and that is why its this will always point to App